# Is it possible for a monitor to evaluate on past 7 days data daily at the time of evaluation? (DataDog)

Tags: alert, distribution, monitor, datadog, datadog-dashboard

I am trying to get the distribution of a certain metric, and once over a certain % threshold, it should alert.

In order to get the distribution, I am dividing the number of each address occurence by total addresses of that blockchain. I want this to evaluate daily, but not only on the current day's data, but also from that evaluation time back 7 days' data as well.

I've tried using rollup and moving rollup, however, it seems they still are only evaluating on data of the last 1 day because of the "Evaluate the maximum of the query over the last 1 day". I don't think I can change this as this is what decides the frequency interval of the evaluation (daily).

I'd like the monitor to be able to evaluate daily, the past 7 days of data.

Thanks a lot.

(In the image I have it set as past 3 days of data for testing).

[image: Metric Query]